# Quickbook WebConnector

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am new to Quickbook. I have created an 30 day trial account on QuickBook online and also created a company there. I wanted to integrate with my existing web application.

Is it possible to use QuickBook WebConnector for synchronization between QuickBook online and my existing web-application.

Or else the QuickBook WebConnector works only with quick book desktop version.

Any link or help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Debajyoti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use QuickBook WebConnector for synchronization between QuickBook online and my existing web-application.

No.

The QuickBooks Web Connector is for QuickBooks desktop (Windows) versions of QuickBooks Online.

Instead, you should look into using the REST v3 APIs documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/us#QuickBooksOnlineAPI

Comment: @SmitPatel  Do a Google search. Then, if you can't find your answer, ask a NEW QUESTION instead of adding a comment on an unrelated one.